# Посоветуйте date-time picker для реакта

Tags: reactjs, frontend, datepicker

Даже на 5й странице гугла ничего нормального не нашёл(

Требования:

1. Поле типа input по нажатию на который открывается календарь.
2. Можно вводить врем/дату как и на прямую в инпут, так и по выбору
   даты в календаре.
3. В пикере должна быть возможность выбрать и дату и время(можно инпут
   с временем отдельно).
4. В либе должен быть range picker(для дат, желательно так же
   возможность выбора времени).
5. Не должно быть PM/AM , либо возможность их отключить.
6. Обязательна возможность локализации, если её нет по дефолту.

Примеры: https://ant.design/components/date-picker . Главные минусы антд - одна коллбек функция на выбор и даты и время, стрёмный дизайн выбора времени(3 скролла).

Если вы пользуетесь или пользовались пикером который подходит под условия пожалуйста дайте ссылку на гитхаб или npm.

Comment: Пользовался таким, посмотрите, может подойдёт: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/

Comment: https://github.com/tresko/react-datepicker